# VML html mail, position of image

Tags: vml

I have made a HTML mail template. This templates works well in all mayor mail clients (gmail, thunderbird etc.), except Outlook 2007/2010. Outlook 2003 displays the mail well.

This is the correct lay-out, the orange header bar is displayed at the right position:

[image: correct display in Outlook 2003]

This is what is wrong with Outlook 2007/2010. The header bar is outside the body, on top of the mail:

[image: Wrong display in Outlook 2007]

Here is my template:

```
  <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
  <title>Wieskamp Nieuwsbrief</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td{font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 12px;color: black;}
.header{font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color: #f4f4be;text-align:center;}
v:* { behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; }
</style>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td background="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-header.jpg" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" width="600" height="226" valign="top">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:226px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-header.jpg" color="#f6f6f6" size="600px,226px"/>
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                    <div>

                    </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td background="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-midden.jpg" bgcolor="#cfd300" width="600" valign="top" style="background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;">
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-midden.jpg" color="#f4f4be" size="600px,6px" />
                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div>           
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                    <td colspan="3" align="center" background="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/header_balk.jpg" bgcolor="#cfd300" width="520" height="26" valign="top" style="color: #f4f4be;font-weight: bold;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;">
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:520px;height:26px;">
                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/header_balk.jpg" color="#f6f6f6" size="520px,26px"/>
                                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                        <![endif]-->
                                        <div>
                                        Headerbalk

                                        </div>
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        </v:textbox>
                                        </v:rect>
                                        <![endif]-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="40"></td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                    <td width="124" valign="top"><img src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/plaatjes.jpg" width="114" height="160"/></td>
                                    <td width="386" valign="top">
                                    <b>Er gaat iets gebeuren</b><br><br>
                                    22 februari 2013<br><br>
                                     De bomen worden weer fris groen, de bloeitijd begint. De lucht geurt van bloesem en het eerste gemaaide gras. De vogels geven hun concert bij de opgaande zon. De lente is een uitstekend jaargetijde om op vakantie te gaan in het Nationale Landschap Winterswijk. 

De lente loopt van maart tot en met juni op Camping Het Wieskamp. Natuurlijk is er met Pasen, Hemelvaart en Pinksteren veel te beleven op het terrein. Maar daarom heen vindt u de rust op de standplaats, en ook erbuiten. Al wandelend of fietsend ontdekt u de nestelende vogels. de bloeiende hoogstamfruitbomen en het frisse groen van de omliggende natuurgebieden. 
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                </tr>
<tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            </table>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                    <td colspan="3" align="center" background="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/header_balk.jpg" bgcolor="#cfd300" width="520" height="26" valign="top" style="color: #f4f4be;font-weight: bold;vertical-align: middle;background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;">
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:520px;height:26px;">
                                        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/header_balk.jpg" color="#f6f6f6" size="520px,26px"/>
                                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                        <![endif]-->
                                        <div>
                                        Headerbalk
                                        </div>
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        </v:textbox>
                                        </v:rect>
                                        <![endif]-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="40"></td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                    <td width="10"></td>
                                    <td width="124" valign="top"><img src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/plaatjes.jpg" width="114" height="160"/></td>
                                    <td width="386" valign="top">
                                    <b>Er gaat iets gebeuren</b><br><br>
                                    22 februari 2013<br><br>
                                     De bomen worden weer fris groen, de bloeitijd begint. De lucht geurt van bloesem en het eerste gemaaide gras. De vogels geven hun concert bij de opgaande zon. De lente is een uitstekend jaargetijde om op vakantie te gaan in het Nationale Landschap Winterswijk. 

De lente loopt van maart tot en met juni op Camping Het Wieskamp. Natuurlijk is er met Pasen, Hemelvaart en Pinksteren veel te beleven op het terrein. Maar daarom heen vindt u de rust op de standplaats, en ook erbuiten. Al wandelend of fietsend ontdekt u de nestelende vogels. de bloeiende hoogstamfruitbomen en het frisse groen van de omliggende natuurgebieden. 
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="40"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td background="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-footer.jpg" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" width="600" height="88" valign="top">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:88px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.wieskamp.nl/media/nieuwsbrief/wieskamp-nieuwsbrief-footer.jpg" color="#f6f6f6" size="600px,88px"/>
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                    <div>

                    </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>


  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @box86rowh unfortunately not...I had to make a redesign.

Comment: Yeah, turns out you cannot nest td's that have VML backgrounds with others that do.  I had to re-invent my template to achieve the same look.

Comment: @box86rowh same here :-)